# How can I slow all zooming in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I built an OpenLayers 3 map. I love it, but I feel that the zooming is too fast. I can't find a way to slow it down. A longer animation duration and/or a fractional-zoom approach (zooming by less than 1 for each event) would help. How can I implement these changes?

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the `duration` property on `ol.control.Zoom`, `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom`, `ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom` and `ol.interaction.KeyboardZoom`:

```
var duration = 1000; // 1 second
map.addControl(new ol.control.Zoom({
  duration: duration
}));
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({
  duration: duration
}));
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom({
    duration: duration
}));
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.KeyboardZoom({
    duration: duration
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works well if you're zooming one level at a time, but it gets very choppy if you zoom quickly through a couple of levels.

Comment: You can also configure your `ol.View` with a different `zoomFactor`. The default is 2. A factor of 1.5 gives you twice as many zoom steps, resulting in slower zooming.

Comment: @sbleon Did you try `@ahocevar` solution?

Comment: @ahocevar that is a perfect solution for me, thanks! If you add it as an answer I will accept it.